# Changing textview using 2 spinners

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, spinner

I have 2 spinners and 1 textview.When i selected two different elements from these spinners textview must be changed everytime.For 1 spinner everything is OK but it doesnt work on 2 spinners.
Here's what i tried:

```
public class Chords extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    String[] notes = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"};
    String[] mode = {"m","m7","5","M","7M","dim","aug","sus2"};
    Spinner sp;
    Spinner spinner2;
    TextView textView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chords_screen);
            System.out.println(notes.length);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        sp= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner2=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_state = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,notes);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_state2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,mode);
        adapter_state.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapter_state2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp.setAdapter(adapter_state);
        sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter_state2);
        sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

     }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                               long id) {

        switch(position)
        {

            case 0:
                textView.setText("Am");
                break;

        }


    }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected (AdapterView < ? > parent){

        }

    }
```

Comment: You set the listener twice for **sp** spinner. Probably copied and not changed for **spinner2**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 spinners. You set onItemSelected listener. but your implementation is wrong i think. In switch case you have to identify which spinner value is changing. you can do like this ..

## I edited all code for you

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
String[] notes = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"};
String[] mode = {"m","m7","5","M","7M","dim","aug","sus2"};
Spinner sp;
Spinner spinner2;
TextView textView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //initialization
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner2=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

    //creating adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_state = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,notes);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_state2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,mode);

    //setting drop down list type 
    adapter_state.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter_state2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    //setting adapter to spinner
    sp.setAdapter(adapter_state);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter_state2);


    //setting listener to spinner
    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch(parent.getId())
    {
        case R.id.spinner:
            textView.setText(""+notes[position]);
            break;
        case R.id.spinner2:
            textView.setText(""+mode[position]);
            break;

    }
}


@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

## To do so edit like this

```
    case R.id.spinner:
        textView.setText(sp.getSelectedItem().toString()+spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString());
        break;
    case R.id.spinner2:
        textView.setText(sp.getSelectedItem().toString()+spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString());
        break;
```

Comment: if anything else you need you can write .. feel free